# Prevent two or three fingers select with radio button in Android

Tags: android

There is 10 radio buttons in recyclerview.
I want to click to radio button and this must be selected after touch. It seems good with one finger but if I use two or more fingers at the same time while choosing 2 or more item from radiobutton, There is multiple selection problem. Just one item must be selected. How can I solve this problem ? How can I prevent 2 or more finger tap?

I controlled it with code below.

```
for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++) { 

if(itemList.get(i).isSelected())

itemList.get(i).setSelected(false); 

} 

itemList.get(position).setSelected(true); 

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You can't prevent the user to tap with 2 or more fingers... Apart from removing all the "not-needed" fingers from the user...

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? Would you like to create a mutual exclusion? Do you have multiple radio buttons and only one should stay selected? Be more clear please

Comment: Yes. There is 10 radio buttons. Only one should stay. This is possible with one finger but when choose with 2 fingers it is doesn't work.

Comment: Show your code, how are you achieving your current solution?

Comment: I edited and added code.

Comment: Do you not want to it shows in the highlighted state while pressing. Or just can the user not select a more one item?

Comment: Yes@Шах, user can't choose more than one item. Just one item.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you would want to use a RadioGroup.

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

In your activity:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

You should read the documentation first: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Comment: I used radiobutton in adapter because I don't know how many data will come client side. Your solution doesn't match mine problem but thank you.

Comment: hmm.,. it's exactly matches to your problem. And this is the most easy way  . . . If you want the hard way implementation . . . implement and disable multi touch . . . . But once again this is the best way.